# Sum value separated by a comma VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I would need a little help making some calculations between the comma.

If I have a set of numbers: 1,7,9,23,25,29,41 - how do I display the sum of these numbers?

Comment: Which part of the task are you having trouble with?  Do you not know how to input the comma delimited string?  Or do you not know how to parse all the integer values out of the input string?  Or is it that you don't know how to sum a list of integers?  Or maybe you don't know how to display the result?  It's not clear what your actual question is.

Comment: Split the string apart on the commas, which gives you an array of strings. Parse each element of that array as an integer and sum them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a one-liner you can split the string to create an array, then use the `Sum` method against the array:

```
Dim myList As String = "1,7,9,23,25,29,41"
Dim sum As Integer = myList.Split(","c).Sum(Function(str) CInt(str))
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what you need:

```
Dim values As String = "1,7,9,23,25,29,41"

Dim arrValues() As String = Split(values, ",")

Dim Total As Integer

For Each value As String In arrValues

Total = Total + CInt(value)

Next

MsgBox("Total: " & Total)
```

Comment: Integers should be initialized to 0.

Comment: @preciousbetine Why? The default value is 0.

Comment: @Mary it was formerly initialized to nothing like `Dim Total As Integer = Nothing`.I haven't tried this but I think when trying to **read** the `Total` value without changing the reference from nothing, a null reference exception would be thrown. *Note that I have not tried it*

Comment: @preciousbetine Agreed. Initializing to Nothing is nonsensical since Integer is a value type.